# There was no endpoint listening at http://192.168.1.15:8080/xxxx/xxxxx.asmx that could accept the message

Tags: c#, web-services, networking

I met a stange phenomenon about C# WebService.
The WebService are always working well on server, but client program will prompt the error message "There was no endpoint listening at ..." when access the WebService many times late. restart the client program can not be working, but restart the client compupter can be working.
I am so confused, can anybody help me? Please...

Comment: You are using a webpage since the port is 8080.  And since you sometimes connect the issue is not a proxy or a credential issue.  So the problem is usually one of two issues. 1) You are not always making a connection.  Which means a time out is occurring or you have a hardware issue on the network.2) You have a cookie being transmitted and the server is refusing to allow more than one connection from the same client.  The server uses the cookie to recognize the same client is trying to make more than one connection.

Comment: @jdweng
Thank you.